# Codes not working

Tags: r

I'm new to R, using it for classification of remote sensing images. I have Code already prepared by my professor, but I can't get it to work. This happens:

```
 source("CompareMethods.R")
Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :
  cannot open file 'CompareMethods.R': No such file or directory
```

Comment: It would appear that the file is not in your working directory. If you are on Windoze or OSX you should realize that sometimes editors will save files with extensions that do not show on the file viewing applications (Windows Explorer or Finder.app.). You should try to understand what your working directory is and what your OS services are providing.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is told by R:

> No such file or directory

With R you're always working in a directory or folder. You can set the working directory when you start with `setwd('path/to/the/folder/with/your/file/in/it')`.

Comment: I suppose that is true, but you do not have enough information to offer a helpful answer since the OP has not said what computing platform he is working on.

Comment: On the contrary, I think S. Fisher might not have set their working directory with `setwd`.

Comment: There would be a default working directory and anyway you have not shown him how to determine what _is_ the working directory.